# Trigger/Setter on dependency property reached by Binding

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, dependency-properties

I want to set a dependency property that I declared in my `Class1` that inherits from `DependencyObject`:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyMouseOverProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyMouseOver", typeof(bool), typeof(Class1), 
                                                                                             new PropertyMetadata(false,new PropertyChangedCallback(On_MyMouseOver)));

    private static void On_MyMouseOver(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
       // some code here

    }

    public bool MyMouseOver
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(MyMouseOverProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyMouseOverProperty, value); }
    }
```

I'll use "MyMouseOver" in XAML in order to use its state in "On_MyMouseOver" to affect another Object.

```
 <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Class1}">
                <Canvas x:Name="Canvas_Classe1"
                        Background="Transparent">

                     <Canvas.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="{Binding Path=MyMouseOver}" Value="True"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Canvas.Triggers>

                </Canvas>
```

but ... this is not working.
How to use `Setter` to access to a `DependencyProperty` declared not within a control but a class ?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with [attached property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/attached-properties-overview)

```
public class Class1 
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyMouseOverProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "MyMouseOver", typeof(bool), typeof(Class1), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, PropertyChangedCallback)
    );

    public static void SetMyMouseOver(UIElement element, Boolean value)
    {
        element.SetValue(MyMouseOverProperty, value);
    }

    public static bool GetMyMouseOver(UIElement element)
    {
        return (bool)element.GetValue(MyMouseOverProperty);
    }

    private static void PropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // some code here
    }
}
```

Set attached property on DataTemplate IsMouseOver

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Class1}">
        <Canvas x:Name="Canvas_Classe1"
                Background="Black">
        </Canvas>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="local:Class1.MyMouseOver" Value="True"/>
            </Trigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply , but where is the "MyMouseOver" in the C# code you added?

Comment: In Class1, same as you wrote in question "I want to set a dependency property that I declared in my Class1". You can replace your DependencyProperty declaration with AttachedProperty declaration, as in my example